# Spring bean as Web Service

Tags: web-services, spring, cxf, apache-axis, spring-ws

Am new to web services. I have a spring bean in which i have used Transactional annotation for DB operations.
Now I need to expose one of the method in the bean as a service.
The method parameters are Hashmap and a POJO (like JPA entity) object. return type is HashMap.

What is the best way to implement it.

1. Directly exposing the bean using Axis2.
2. Using Spring-Ws with CXF.
3. Writing a new method in a new wrapper class which accepts Strings as parameters.
   (These string are actually as required by  the original Map and POJO ). 
   And by setting these strings as properties and objects in POJO and Map respectively, as required by original method.
4. The Third method wont work in my case as the Map will contains several arraylists which needs to be stored in DB.So I have to use Map only.

Shall I go with SOAP or RESt.
Already two web services were provided using Axis2 in our project by old team.
We are using spring 3 (as core container and for ORM), Hibernate template, Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that question is best answered by yourself. We can only give hints here which framework and technology might work out best for you. In order to give any hint, we'd need some more information about your project.

SOAP and REST, for example, are two essentially different technologies. The SOAP protocol must use XML as information medium and can use literally any transport medium, e.g. HTTP, E-Mail, JMS, etc. Using SOAP, the contract, which is the WSDL specification, between a service endpoint and a client is the interface description. The REST protocol can use any information medium, e.g. JSON, XML, YAML, etc., but is limited to the HTTP protocol as transport medium. Here, the HTTP methods like DELETE, GET, POST are the interface description.

You said, you're actually using AXIS2. If your experiences with that framework are good enough, I would recommend to use it further. CXF is simply another Web Service Framework which **cannot** be used together with Spring-WS (but it can be used with the Spring Framework). Here, I would consider that each framework has its caveats and needs some time to learn.